# Is this headlight cover corrupted? (Small cracks from an angle)

Tags: vw, headlight

VW Passat Variant B8 2017 - I'd like to make low beams more bright so I decided to buy better bulbs but I noticed the covers have small cracks inside when looking from some angles.

Is this a problem? Should I replace or have them fixed?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you're talking about all the spots, I would have no doubt believing those are on the *outside* of the lense, not the inside. I'd lay a wager a lense restoration kit would easily take care of them.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Yes I'm talking about them. I meant it's inside the plastic. Thanks

Comment: Please, pretty please, get new headlights and replace these tools for blinding the oncoming traffic

Comment: I skimmed the second line really quickly and thought it said "should I replace the headlight fluid?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everyday driving puts small scratches and chips in the lens. That along with the impact of UV light from the sun distorts the light beam as it passes through the lens. The light gets scattered and looses focus. Installing a brighter bulb will offset the distortion to some extent. Another alternative is to polish the lens with any of the lens repair kits available. The repair kits only work for a limited time depending on the brand and driving conditions. At some point replacing the lens becomes the best repair.

Answer (score 5):

This answer pretty much coincides with @mikes' answer, with a little different understanding of what's best.

The pits/marks on your headlight covers can easily be taken care of with a polishing kit and can be done at home, even with minimal knowledge of what you're doing. There are a ton of YouTube videos out there to show you how to do it. This polishing can be done many times before the need to replace them occurs. To have the best longevity out of your covers after polishing, you need to put a good quality carnauba wax on them to keep the UV light at bay. It's not just the light which causes issues, it's light when combined with oxygen which hazes them over time. The wax keeps the oxygen off of them and over time and with proper maintenance will help them last a LOT longer. Realistically, polishing and wax will allow the headlight covers to last as long as you own your car.